# How to call async function to use return on global scope

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, scope, async-await

I'm currently struggling with a `function` call, when I call the function from an `if` statement it does work but when I call it from outside it doesn't, my `if` statement only checks which button was pressed but I'm trying to remove the function from the button and just call it as soon as my app starts.

We will look at `fetchJokes()` inside `jokeContainer.addEventListener('click', event => {`

This is my current code:

```
const jokeContainer = document.querySelector('.joke-container');
const jokesArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("jokesData"));

// Fetch joke count from API endpoint
async function sizeJokesArray() {
  let url = 'https://api.icndb.com/jokes/count';
  let data = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  data = data.value;
  return data;
}

// use API endpoint to fetch the jokes and store it in an array
async function fetchJokes() {
  let url = `https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/${length}`;
  let jokesData = [];
  let data = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  data = data.value;
  for (jokePosition in data) {
    jokesData.push(data[jokePosition].joke);
  }
  return localStorage.setItem("jokesData", JSON.stringify(jokesData));;
}

const jokeDispenser = (function() {
  let counter = 0; //start counter at position 0 of jokes array
  function _change(position) {
    counter += position;
  }
  return {
    nextJoke: function() {
      _change(1);
      counter %= jokesArray.length; // start from 0 if we get to the end of the array
      return jokesArray[counter];
    },
    prevJoke: function() {
      if (counter === 0) {
        counter = jokesArray.length; // place our counter at the end of the array
      }
      _change(-1);
      return jokesArray[counter];
    }
  };
})();

// pass selected joke to print on html element
function printJoke(joke) {
  document.querySelector('.joke-text p').textContent = joke;
}

sizeJokesArray().then(size => (length = size)); // Size of array in response

jokeContainer.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.value === 'Fetch') {    
    fetchJokes(length);
  } else if (event.target.value === 'Next') {
    printJoke(jokeDispenser.prevJoke(jokesArray));
  } else if (event.target.value === 'Prev') {
    printJoke(jokeDispenser.nextJoke(jokesArray));
  }
});
```

And I'm trying to do something like this:

```
// pass selected joke to print on HTML element
function printJoke(joke) {
  document.querySelector('.joke-text p').textContent = joke;
}

sizeJokesArray().then(size => (length = size)); // Size of array in response
fetchJokes(length);

jokeContainer.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.value === 'Next') {
    printJoke(jokeDispenser.prevJoke(jokesArray));
  } else if (event.target.value === 'Prev') {
    printJoke(jokeDispenser.nextJoke(jokesArray));
  }
});
```

By the way, I'm aware that currently, you can't actually iterate through the array elements using prev and next button without refreshing the page but I guess that will be another question.

Couldn't think of a better title.(edits welcomed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async functions are, as the name implies, *asynchronous*. In

```
sizeJokesArray().then(size => (length = size)); // Size of array in response
fetchJokes(length);
```

you are calling `fetchJokes` **before** `length = size` is executed because, as you may have guessed, `sizeJokesArray` is asynchronous.

But since you are already using promises the fix is straightforward:

```
sizeJokesArray().then(fetchJokes);
```

---

If you have not fully understood yet how promises work, maybe https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises helps.

Comment: So why can I just call it as `fetchJokes()` inside my `if` statement?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `if` statement. The reason it works is that the call is inside an event handler. By the time you click on the DOM element and the event handler is executed, the Ajax response will have been received and `length = size` will have been executed. I.e. `length` has a value other than `0`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I get it now but why does that happen? As in why when the DOM element is clicked the Ajax response has been received and before that it hasn't.

Comment: If you open the network tab in your browser's developer tools you will see how long the network request takes. It will likely be only a couple of hundred milliseconds. I assume a lot more time passes between making the request and the page rendering something you can click on. But that only explains why it works in the event handler. It does not work in `sizeJokesArray().then(size => (length = size));
fetchJokes(length);` because the way JavaScript works *guarantees* that `fetchJokes(length)` is called *before* `size => (length = size)` is executed. It's called "run-to-completion" ....

Comment: ... see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop for more info on that. I.e. even if the response was received instantaneously, JavaScript would not hold the current execution to execute the callback. It will finish the current execution, which includes calling `fetchJokes` and binding the event handler, and *then* it would process the response.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :) Keep it up!